# Should we always accept a better answer, or also reward response speed?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Case in point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959059/how-to-avoid-square-brackets-when-converting-list-to-json-using-jsonlitetojson). Akrun gave a great answer in ~2 minutes. Grada's answer is slightly better (because it's simpler and more generalizable), but came in a little later (but still before Akrun's answer was accepted).

Whose to accept? Should speed be rewarded, or should we always accept the better answer?

Comment: It's not a race. Always try to accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: In general, I follow @Clive in Accepting the answer that is the _most_ helpful - and I won't hesitate to unaccept an answer if a better one comes along. I will also, however, upvote other answers that are helpful, if they provide information that is not in the Accepted answer.

Comment: @Sonic Interestingly, the answer says "you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally", which, at least to me, personally, gives a different indication to the Clive's comment above, since I value quick answers, or at least I really did in that case